# How do you find out who has impersonated the GCP Service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I was working on a requirement wherein there is a need to know which user/machine has actually created the instances.

For example if a Compute Instance has been created by a Service account, how do we come to know which user had created. Basically, the intention is if we could capture the IP address/MAC address to check for any security flaw ?

Any hints are more than welcome !!!

Comment: 1/2) Anyone with the service account key can use the service account. There is no direct method to track this. If a user logs in to a Compute Engine instance, the auth.log will record who/when someone logged in. However, you must manually setup Stackdriver to log this file. For the IP address, this is logged to Stackdriver for each recorded action with the service account identity. However, there is no matchup of a logged in user and the act of using the service account. That will have to be deduced. An OS service could be using a service account as well.

Comment: 2/2) A service account is an identity. It is possible to "assume" a service account identity but this is rare in Google Cloud. The service account in its simplest form is just a secret key. There is no tie back to who is using it. You must implement strategies to issue separate keys to each user to track their usage. Example, only give user Bob service account X. Then you can imply that Bob is the user from access logs in Stackdriver. Otherwise, you have to reverse engineer the activity.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for the information. I believe, setting up a process to control who accesses the service account for which activity would be the best way to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Listing members that can access a service account
Select a project. Click the email address of the service account that you want to allow the member to impersonate. Click the Permissions tab. The Members with access to this service account section lists the members that can access the service account.
You can find the entire process of impersonating service accounts in [1]
[1][https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#:~:text=Listing%20members%20that%20can%20access%20a%20service%20account,-Use%20the%20Cloud&text=Select%20a%20project.,can%20access%20the%20service%20account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#:%7E:text=Listing%20members%20that%20can%20access%20a%20service%20account,-Use%20the%20Cloud&text=Select%20a%20project.,can%20access%20the%20service%20account).

Answer (score 1):

When a user invokes `gcloud` with the `--impersonate-service-account` argument, a log message is generated in the **project where the service account is defined**:

```
resource.type="service_account" resource.labels.email_id="sa-name@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
protoPayload.methodName="GenerateAccessToken"
```

When a GCE instance is created, a log message that lists the principal and the impersonator is generated in the **project where the vm was created**.

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
resource.labels.zone="us-central1-a"
protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.insert"
protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="sa-name@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

The value you're looking for is in `protoPayload.serviceAccountDelegationInfo`.  The caller's IP is in `protoPayload.requestMetadata.callerIp`.

Comment: Note that in order for the call to "GenerateAccessToken" to be logged, you need to enable IAM audit logging as specified here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging